# NumPy/SciPy: Move mask over Image and check for equality

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, scipy

I am trying to do image processing using [NumPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) and [scipy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SciPy). I have a template image corresponding to a background, and I want to find out all the places where it occurs in the input image and set the corresponding array positions in the output to 1, else set them to 0. How can I do this?

Comment: Corrected spelling error in the question title for you. Anyway, how large is your template image in relation to the input image, as a rough average? Do you want to do image processing for exact matches, or do you want to be able to detect scaled versions, slightly different ones, etc.?

Comment: My template is not big compared to image, ~100 pixels. Other than exact match I want to do ±x where x is small perturbation of to adjust for smaller variations in image intensity.

Answer (score 3):

You can use scipy.ndimage.correlate to correlate your template against the image. Then look for bright spots which will give you your matches. Example:

```
import scipy.ndimage
from numpy import mean, std

# a, b contain image and template in numpy arrays
correlation = scipy.ndimage.correlate(a, b)
matches = (correlation-mean(correlation)) > 5*std(correlation) # tune depending on level of noise
```

Comment: "Then look for bright spots which will give you your matches." I am new to using numpy, how will I accomplish that.

Comment: @Xolve that is the idea of the last line in the example - basically look for points that are some number of standard deviations above the  mean image value. You can use the command imshow to have a quick look at the result and tune for your case, or if you post a link to some sample images I will give it a try.